# Jquery Attribute value marge

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add an attribute from span's attribute to href of an anchor. It's overwriting existing href i.e. `callto:` value. I want it to append like this `<a class="phone" href="callto:000-555-6666"></a>`. How can I do that? Thanks!

**HTML**

```
<a class="phone" href="callto:"></a>
<span class="path" phone="000-555-6666">Test</span>
```

**JQuery**

```
jQuery(".path").mousemove(function(e) {
  jQuery(".phone").attr('href', jQuery(this).attr('phone')).attr(jQuery(this).attr('phone'));
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're over-complicating the things here. Simply get the attribute value, and set it using the `attr` function:

```js
jQuery(".path").mousemove(function(e) {
  var phone = $(this).attr('phone');
  jQuery(".phone").attr('href', 'callto:' + phone);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="phone" href="callto:">test</a>
<span class="path" phone="000-555-6666">Test</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are replacing existing value. Add the "call to:" with phone attribute value and then set the href attribute.

```js
jQuery(".path").mousemove(function(e) {
  jQuery(".phone").attr('href',"callto:"+ jQuery(this).attr('phone'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="phone" href="callto:"></a>
<span class="path" phone="000-555-6666">Test</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery(".path").mousemove(function(e) {
     var phone = jQuery(this).attr('phone');
     jQuery(".phone").attr('href','callto:'+phone);
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="phone" href="callto:">Phone Number</a>
<span class="path" phone="000-555-6666">Test</span>
```

In the question you don't have any text for the  tag so you have to add that.
and from js side, you have to take the current attr value of the span and add this to the  tag.